# How to import one table in sqlyog?

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

If import database in sqlyog :

- right-click on the database
- import
- execute sql script

I need to import one table in sqlyog

How to import one table in sqlyog?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to import a single object/table, you will need to generate the SQL dump for each object separately, which can be done using Scheduled Backup option which gives the option to generate Separate file for each object.

You can then import that required SQL file using the option you have mentioned.